# If a model predicts that a loan will default, what is the probability that it will actually default?

Tags: probability

The loan default at a certain bank is $1\%$. the bank has developed a model to try to predict which loans will default. The model's predicted positive rate is $3\%$; $99\%$ of the loans that default are predicted as such by the model. If a model predicts that a loan will default, what is the probability that it will actually default?

Comment: Already from the fact that the model predict three times as many defaults than reality, we can conclude that the probability is at most $\frac13$. The fact that almost all actual defaults are also predicted then tells us that $\frac13$ is almost exactly the right answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple application of Bayes formula

$$P(\text{default} | \text{predicted default})=\frac{P(\text{predicted default} | \text{default})P(\text{default})}{P(\text{predicted default})}$$

$$=\frac{0.99\times 0.01}{0.03}=0.33$$